# Azure Web App - Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-web-app-service

I have several Azure Web Apps using the MS Report Viewer to generate PDFs from RDLC files.

Two days ago these were working fine.

None of the apps have been changed since then, but all are now failing to generate PDFs, with the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The stack trace on the YSOD looks like this:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(Object obj, Boolean verify, Boolean assertOnInvalidType) +0
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.WriteVariantOrPersistable(Object obj) +73
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateHashForCachedDataSets() +272
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash) +92
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Byte[] definition, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash) +82
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash) +165
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection) +189

[ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.]
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection) +989
   Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot) +203

[DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid.]
   Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot) +269
   Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot) +228
   Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport() +29
   Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport() +5
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession() +61

[LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession() +150
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings) +83
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings) +119
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings) +31
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.Render(String format) +71
```

All other functionality appears to be fine - it's just the PDF generation that's failed.

How can this have just stopped working across the board? Has Azure changed in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We faced the same issue and ended up installing the package from nuget to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks - this definitely fixes the problem, but it would be nice to know why it suddenly started happening.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, the version of the package you use doesn't seem to matter - using either 12.0.4100.1 or 14.0.314.76 (the latest) fixed it, so you can install the package without specifying a version: Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to get the current one.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with our web app which uses entity framework and sql coordinates.  All was working fine until Dec 1 2017, and then we got the same error.  I had previously had a binding redirect in our web.config for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types which redirected to v13.  I updated it to point to v14:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I also added the nuget package to be safe, but i am thinking i did not need to. 
 I'm guessing that the v13 was updated to v14 in azure.

Note:  I did **not** follow the nuget package readme instructions which was to add to the global asax file:             SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));

**EDIT**:  I confirmed that i did not need to add the nuget package.  Instead, my resolution was to adjust the binding redirect in my web.config to point to version 14.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue yesterday (Nov 29, 2017) where all of our Azure environments start reporting the same issue. Suggested fix by Murakri does fix it

Would be nice to find out what exactly happened?

Comment: Yes - it would be nice to know what suddenly changed. I tweeted @AzureSupport and they said they'd respond here, but nothing yet...